# Retrieve ID of newly created user Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm studying `Angular2` and the latest version of `Firebase` I have the following Firebase set up in my project, which is used for creating a new user based of email and password:

```
signUpUser(user: User) {
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

The user is created successfully, but how do I go about retrieving the newly created user id? I've gone through the documentation and not one section explains how I can retrieve it after the user has been created? can someone shed some light into how you go about doing this?

Comment: Rather than update the question, if that code resolves your issue, you could add it as a [self answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Or just delete the question. A question with an answer in it isn't going to be useful to anyone else.

Comment: @cartant, good point, made the modifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to resolve this question my self, by adding an enhancement to the code specified in the original question:

```
signUpUser(user: User) {
   firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password).then(function (user) {
   console.log('uid', user.uid)
 }).catch(function (error) {
   console.log(error);
 });
}
```